# bulk image upload in android

Tags: java, android, file-upload, bulk

I have an application which i need to upload 10 images ( max ) to the server . first i upload all images in a single thread one after another and each time recycling `Bitmap` map and give the `GC` a hint by `System.gc();` now this works fine ,but the problem more time the user need to wait to upload the images . so I tried to upload each 2 images in a thread using `ThreadPoolExecuter` now using this method ,the app can run out of memory on small RAM devices . The question is : is there a better solution to send the images quickly without consuming alot of memory ?

Comment: What images do you upload (loaded from file or generate din your app)? How do you upload the image directly from an Bitmap instance?

Comment: @Robert , the image is picked from camera or gallery , what i do i compress the bitmaps then send them to the server

Comment: can you please upload the code, you are already using ?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the AsynTask to do the background work. in this you will have overridden method call doInBackground. in which you can upload the images to the server and it will be very efficient since it's async call. so you can still have your UI changes parallel.

Comment: What i meant for this is. if your uploading of images in the background then user will never know like images are being uploaded.

Comment: i am using an AsyncTask and progress dialog appear to the user .